# The API License Key is NOT valid in Enhanced Kudan Samples

Tags: ios, kudan

When I use the following code in my `AppDelegate` class in Xcode, it should normally let me access the API from 'Enhanced Kudan Samples' but it doesn't let me, it says the key is invalid. But I got this key from their site. Does anyone have a valid key?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[ARAPIKey sharedInstance] setAPIKey:@"GAWQE-F9AQU-2G87F-8HKED-Q7BTG-TY29G-RV85A-XN3ZP-A9KGM-E8LB6-VC2XW-VTKAK-ANJLG-2P8NX-UZMAH-Q"];

    return YES;
}
```

The project is run successfully but when I open any screen other than the camera it displays a black screen and doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using version 1.4 of the framework, you need to use the very long key at the bottom. The key you have used is for use with version 1.3.1 and below.

```
[[ARAPIKey sharedInstance] setAPIKey:@"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"];
```

> use bundle id= eu.kudan.ar

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that the API Key (Which is publicly available, so it's fine) in the original question is different from the one in the edit, the problem is probably that you're using Version 1.4 of the framework, which uses a new licensing format, so won't work with that style of key anymore. Note the lower portion of the [Development License Keys](https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys) page, where it says:

> "For the API License Key that has come out with v1.4, you can use following bundle / key."

and then provides a *very* long key for you to use with version 1.4.

Your solution, therefore, is to copy and paste the new license key in place of the old one. Your app will then work provided it is using the *eu.kudan.ar* Bundle Identifier, since that's the only one working with the new licensing for now.